# css position:fixed <script> tag within does not stay fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, fixed

I'm having an issue trying to get a .js validation script to stay in a fixed location within a webpage.

My code for the css is:

```
div.fixed {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="fixed">
<script src="http://my.gblearn.com/js/javascript.js"></script>
</div>
```

I can add anything inside that div tag and it will rise above the top and stay fixed to the bottom left, but the javascript file will just stay where I've placed it within the webpage as if it can't be bothered to adhere to the .css rule.

I was wondering how I could get around this. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You're attempting to add an actual **script** itself to your DIV, not the output **from** the script. That just tells the page that you should load the script, like you would load a CSS file in the `<head>` section. You can't simply 'position' it, because it is never actually rendered. Assuming your script is adding content to the DOM, you'll need to craft the JavaScript to output into `.fixed`, or use CSS to target the element that the JavaScript inserts to. **And** for what it's worth, your JavaScript link is a 404 anyway.

Comment: Sounds like whatever that script is adds stuff to the DOM outside of the element it's in. The script doesn't have any content from what I can tell - what does it do? Can you share the source?

Comment: You added style for your script tag? Why?

Comment: The script source was not found http://my.gblearn.com/js/javascript.js

Comment: The .js file is for validating the web page. Teachers have us implement it into our code so that they can see a) a time stamp for last edited b) that the code is verified for css and then html.

My website contains a spliced 16:9 ratio image that scales to the size of the browser window depending on the monitor size. If I put the script tag in, it can only go in at the bottom and the site no long scales. I was hoping to keep this floating above everything to get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much toying around, we figured out that viewing the source code for my website, we could see the javascript output. The .js file showed id's and we made a .css portion of the code to show the outputted information like so:

css

```
nav, #gblearn_message_holder {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: auto;
}
```

html

```
<div id="gblearn_message_holder">
<a title="Validate this page" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="GBLEARN_TESTER.validatePage(this.form)">
<img src="http://my.gblearn.com/img/HTML5_Logo_2561.png" alt="html5 validator">
</a><a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
<img style="border:0;width:99px;height:31px" src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss-blue" alt="Valid CSS!"></a>
<br>This page was last modified on 3/29/2017, 7:17:04 PM</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The script element allows authors to include dynamic script and data
>   blocks in their documents. The element does not represent content for
>   the user.

The quotes above was extracted from this link [here](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-script-element.html)

The `script` is not a content layout html container but serves to the purpose of dynamic execution of blocks of codes that can `produce` a layout/expected output .Hence you will find certain css rules applied on a script tag  void.

Comment: Is there anyway I can say "display output to the div container", so that the .js output will go where I tell it to?

Answer (score 0):

script tag not add in div mention bottom after footer try this one

```css
div.fixed {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
height:50px; width:50px; background:#888;
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
<h3> hii </h3>
</div>

<script src="http://my.gblearn.com/js/javascript.js"></script>
```